# React Bootstrap select option renders and does not display first available option when list renewed

Tags: reactjs, select, bootstrap-4, dropdown

The project uses React Bootstrap https://react-bootstrap.github.io/
The app receives a list of buckets from api. There are two select dropdowns. The objective here is that the same bucket can not be selected in both selects. So if the first select has "Red" bucket selected, the second dropdown can not have "Red" in its list.
I have achieved that the second list gets created and the states are updated correctly. But when the second dropdown rerenders, in certain situation, it shows the wrong entry as selected.

The steps:

1. initial load:

The 1st list [Red, Green, Blue]. Selected: Red. 
The 2nd list [Green, Blue]. Selected: Green

2. in the first dropdown select Green:

The 2nd list [Red, Blue]. But the selected option is Blue. It should be Red, as it is the first available from the list.

I understand that it may be because Red was not previously in the list of the 2nd dropdown. But shouldn't that matter? Seeing that the list has been updated and the component has rerendered.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import ToBucket from "./toBucket";

class Buckets extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fromBucketList: [],
      toBucketList: [],
      selectedFromBucket: [],
      selectedToBucket: [],
    };
  }

  handleFromBucketChange = (event) => {
    let nam = event.target.name;
    let bucketId = event.target.value;
    const selectedFromBucket = this.getBucketById(bucketId);
    let rebuiltToBucketList = [...this.state.fromBucketList];
    let selectedFromBucketIndex = rebuiltToBucketList.indexOf(
      selectedFromBucket
    );
    rebuiltToBucketList.splice(selectedFromBucketIndex, 1);
    this.setState({ toBucketList: rebuiltToBucketList });
    this.setState({ [nam]: selectedFromBucket });
    this.setState({ selectedToBucket: rebuiltToBucketList[0] });
  };

  handleToBucketChange = (event) => {
    let nam = event.target.name;
    let bucketId = event.target.value;
    const selectedToBucket = this.getBucketById(bucketId);
    this.setState({ [nam]: selectedToBucket });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const buckets = [
      { id: 1, color: "red" },
      { id: 2, color: "green" },
      { id: 3, color: "blue" },
    ];

    let initialToBucketList = [...buckets];
    initialToBucketList.splice(0, 1);

    this.setState({ fromBucketList: buckets });
    this.setState({ toBucketList: initialToBucketList });
    this.setState({ selectedFromBucket: buckets[0] });
    this.setState({ selectedToBucket: initialToBucketList[0] });
  }

  getBucketById = (id) => {
    let foundedBucket = this.state.fromBucketList.find(
      (element) => element.id == id
    );
    return foundedBucket;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Form noValidate validated={this.state.validated}>
          <Form.Group controlId="SelectFromBucket">
            <Form.Label>Select FROM bucket:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              required
              type="text"
              as="select"
              onChange={this.handleFromBucketChange}
              name="selectedFromBucket"
            >
              {this.state.fromBucketList.map((bucket) => (
                <option key={bucket.id} value={bucket.id}>
                  {bucket.color}
                </option>
              ))}
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <React.Fragment>
            <ToBucket
              handleToBucketChange={this.handleToBucketChange}
              toBucketList={this.state.toBucketList}
            />
          </React.Fragment>
          <p>
            From :{this.state.selectedFromBucket.color}
            <br></br>
            To :{this.state.selectedToBucket.color}
          </p>
        </Form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Buckets;
```

The 2nd dropdown:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";

class ToBucket extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Form.Group controlId="SelectToBucket">
          <Form.Label>Select TO bucket:</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            required
            type="text"
            as="select"
            onChange={this.props.handleToBucketChange}
            name="selectedToBucket"
          >
            {this.props.toBucketList.map((bucket) => (
              <option key={bucket.id} value={bucket.id}>
                {bucket.color}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default ToBucket;
```

I would prefer an answer that is not a workaround or hack for this code, but a conceptual guide to another directions if this aproach is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FormControl of the second dropdown might not change its value because there is no value props passing to it.

Try passing the selected value from the first bucket to the second bucket as props

I never use react-bootstrap but this snippet should works.

**First Component**

```js
<ToBucket
   value={this.state.selectedToBucket && this.state.selectedToBucket.id}
   handleToBucketChange={this.handleToBucketChange}
   toBucketList={this.state.toBucketList}
/>
```

**Second Component**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";

class ToBucket extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Form.Group controlId="SelectToBucket">
          <Form.Label>Select TO bucket:</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            required
            value={this.props.value}
            type="text"
            as="select"
            onChange={this.props.handleToBucketChange}
            name="selectedToBucket"
          >
            {this.props.toBucketList.map((bucket) => (
              <option key={bucket.id} value={bucket.id}>
                {bucket.color}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default ToBucket;
```

Comment: Yes, it helped. Although, could you explain what {this.state.selectedToBucket && this.state.selectedToBucket.id} means? Why {this.state.selectedToBucket.id} is not enough? Thanks.

Comment: `{this.state.selectedToBucket.id}` is enough.

I used `{this.state.selectedToBucket && this.state.selectedToBucket.id}` to validate `this.state.selectedToBucket` that it is not null or undefined which can cause `cannot read property 'id' of undefined` or `cannot read property 'id' of null`.

Your code should not make `this.state.selectedToBucket` to be undefined or null but if there are some bugs, validating can prevent the browser to error.